# Does angular protractor has its own encryption and decryption functions?

Tags: javascript, selenium, encryption, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Does the protractor has any function that could work like encryption and decryption?
I have a password need to write into `config.js` or `specs.js` directly, I donot want other user to get it without launch the test.